# compare data in two files one has 2 column while other has 3 column

Tags: text-processing, join

I have two files:

File 1:

```
Chromosome   Position
Chr1    5242097
Chr1    4876397
Chr1    9474943
Chr1    8494518
Chr1    39872693
Chr1    9445153
Chr1    23044399
Chr1    8018859
Chr1    9474943
Chr1    42380010
Chr1    9474943
Chr1    22677151
Chr1    23044399
Chr1    42380010
```

File 2:

```
Chr1    1   0
Chr1    2   0
Chr1    3   0
Chr1    4   0
Chr1    5   0
Chr1    6   0
Chr1    7   0
Chr1    8   0
Chr1    9   0
Chr1    10  0
Chr1    11  0
Chr1    12  0
Chr1    13  0
Chr1    14  0
Chr1    15  0
Chr1    16  0
Chr1    17  0
Chr1    18  0
Chr1    19  0
Chr1    20  0
Chr1    21  0
Chr1    22  0
Chr1    23  0
Chr1    24  0
Chr1    25  0
Chr1    26  0
Chr1    27  0
Chr1    28  0
Chr1    29  0
Chr1    30  0
Chr1    31  0
Chr1    32  0
Chr1    33  0
Chr1    34  0
Chr1    35  0
Chr1    36  0
Chr1    37  0
Chr1    38  0
Chr1    39  0
Chr1    40  0
Chr1    41  0
Chr1    42  0
Chr1    43  0
Chr1    44  0
Chr1    45  0
Chr1    46  0
Chr1    47  0
Chr1    48  0
Chr1    49  0
Chr1    50  0
```

File2 is very big so I am not showing the entire thing. The numbers can rise to more than 6 digits.

I want to fetch the 3rd column from file2 if it matches the second column of file1.

I have written a Perl program but is is very slow. I am looking for a fast way to do this. Grep is slow as well.

Comment: have you used `diff`?

Comment: Can you post your source code or otherwise describe the approach you used to solve the problem? If the program repeatedly re-reads the second file, for example, the performance will suffer regardless of the tools used.

Comment: Is file1 also very long? Are the files sorted? I assume you only want to print the value from file 2 if both column1 and column2 of file 1 match, right? Is the first field (the chromosome) always `chr1` in both files? What is your desired output? Only column 3 or all three columns from file2?

Comment: You should post sample data with at least some successful matches.

Answer (score 3):

I'd write

```
awk '
    # store column 2 from the first file
    NR == FNR {pos[$2] = 1; next}

    # from the second file, print the 3rd field if it occurred in file1
    $3 in pos {print $3}
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep only col2 from file 1

```
awk '{print $2}' file1 > file1_col2
```

Then keep col3 from file2:

```
awk '{print $3}'  file2> file2_col3
```

Now search for occurrences of file1_col2 rows in file2_col3:

```
grep -f file1_col2 file2_col3
```

Comment: For performance, I'd add the `-F` and `-x` options to grep.

Answer (score 2):

If slow, C++ should help, seriously, it could be used to write quick stuff too =). Save to file.cc and compile with `g++ file.cc -O2 -o file`, run as `./file` in the directory with file; replace `firstfilename` and second one with file names you need before compilation.

You'll be unable to beat C++ in speed =)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   ifstream f1("firstfilename"), f2("secondfilename");
   string s;
   int i1, i2, line=0;
   while (!f1.eof()) {
      line++;
      if (f2.eof()) {
         cout << "Length different!" << "\n";
      }
      f1>>s>>i1;
      f2>>s>>i2>>i2;
      if (i1 != i2) {
         cout << "Not matching line " << line << " " << i1 << "<>" << i2 << "\n";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: In `f1>>s>>i;`, what is `i`? Is it a line number or a string length?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question, hold on for second! =)

Comment: Even simpler =)

Comment: my question still stands

Comment: There is no i anymore. i1 and i2 are just variables to temporary hold values read from files.

Comment: My question is "what is that value"? Sigh, nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

If your first file is small enough to fit in memory, you can do this in Perl:

```
perl -e 'open($f1,"file1"); while(<$f1>){chomp; $k{$_}++}
         while(<>){ /(.+?\s+.+?)\s/; print if defined($k{$1})' file2
```

That should be reasonably fast but it still needs to read the entire `file2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join), include [`sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) if your data isn't sorted by the appropriate field.

```
join -1 2 -2 3 -o 2.3 <(sort -k2,2 file1) <(sort -k3,3 file2)
```

If `sort` isn't needed:

```
join -1 2 -2 3 -o 2.3 file1 file2
```

This is using GNU utilities. For other variants I would need to know what Unix you're using. The version above with `sort` is shown with Bash process substitution which also works in some other shells.

Since the join field is also the output field, `-o 2.3` can be simplified to `-o 0`.